# Python Download File halts when packets loss occurs

Tags: python, download, urllib2, urllib

I am trying to download zip files ranging between 7-30 MB. Sometimes 4 or 5 files will make it through, but here recently I can't get even 1 file downloaded. My script does not throw an error, the connection just stops receiving data. After pinging the source website and watching my network monitor, the downloading seems to stop exactly at the ping where "Request timed out".

I have tried urllib2, urllib, and httplib2.

With urllib2 I have tried:

```
remoteFile = urllib2.urlopen(url)
content = remoteFile.read()
remoteFile.close()

f = open(fpath, 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

and

```
req = Request(url)
# Open the url
f = urlopen(req)
# Open our local file for writing
local_file = open(fpath, "wb")
#Write to our local file
local_file.write(f.read())
local_file.close()
```

With urllib:

```
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
# Open our local file for writing
local_file = open(fpath, "wb")
#Write to our local file
local_file.write(f.read())
local_file.close()
```

With httplib2:

```
h = httplib2.Http(".cache")
resp, content = h.request(url, "GET")
f = open(fpath, 'wb')
f.write(content)
f.close()
```

I even tried downloading in chunks:

```
req = urllib2.urlopen(url)
downloaded = 0
CHUNK = 256 * 10240
with open(file, 'wb') as fp:
    while True:
        chunk = req.read(CHUNK)
        downloaded += len(chunk)
        print str(downloaded/1000000.0) + 'Mb'
        if not chunk: break
        fp.write(chunk)
```

but it just stopped after the 3rd chunk because of the missing packet. I have tried these on smaller downloads from other sites so I know that I am coding them correctly. Again, it never throws an error. The Python module doesn't close for a very long time 20 minutes or longer when the connection closes.

I finally had to give up and just write in C#. So far, I haven't had a problem. Does python not handle packet loss?

Comment: Have you tried setting a timeout with urllib2.urlopen? http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.urlopen

Comment: I would use [paramiko](http://www.lag.net/paramiko/) to download files...